# How to find Ultimecia Castle

Tags: final-fantasy-8

I was playing Final Fantasy VIII ages ago, and I had to stop for a while (technical difficulties, and real life preventing me taking the time to solve them). It's been several years at least, but I recently picked up my old save again. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to progress.

The save says I'm still on disc 3, but there's nothing left to do. I have Ragnarok, I have all GF's except Eden, I have everyone's best weapon, I've farmed four sets of all magic except Ultima (I was farming the Elnoyle in Esthar city when last I played), and most early locations don't have anything left. I've been back to Tear's Point, Trabia Garden, Fisherman's Horizon, Shimi Village, Lunatic Pandora Laboratory, Lunar Gate, and Esthar City, among others, and it seems like I've accomplished everything.

I've also been back to the orphanage. I cannot get to the lighthouse. Cid and Edea are both there, and Edea admonishes me to be patient with Rinoa.

I have read ahead some to try to figure this out on my own. It seems like maybe I should enter the obelisk floating above Tear's Point, but I can't see find how to do that, and it feels like I've played that sequence before.

I also have vague memories of seeing and climbing the chains leading into the castle. I wonder that I have done that and then taken a portal out of the castle... but if so, how do I re-enter? And why does my save game say "Disc 3"?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Heh, this game really is something when it comes to technical difficulties. I was inside the castle on disc 4 when it also crashed. But... the save got corrupted. I got half way through disc 1 again before I gave up.

Comment: In this case, iirc my old system from a few generations back had just died... not the game's fault. I recently found the old save file among a bunch of other stuff I had recovered from the drive but never had time to go through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out last night... I needed to go to Esthar and talk to Pres. Laguna again before I was able to move forward.

In the meantime, all the hunting around meant I was able to beat Ultima Weapon (including drawing Eden) and finish the Shimi Village Statue quest :)

Watching the Lunatic Pandora scenes and the start of Disc 4 again, I'm sure I've played that part before, which lead to my confusion. I have vague recollections now of my old system crashing during that section (why I stopped playing), where it wasn't properly saving my progress and I lost some work.

Comment: oh, i totally forgot about seeing Laguna in Esthar before entering Lunatic Pandora but after you get the Ragnarok. i thought he turned up on the Ragnarok after it makes it back from Space to explain the situation with Adel

Comment: Aaaaand done. Got past Ultimecia on the first attempt, didn't even do anything special :)

Answer (score 5):

Ultimecia Castle is in Disk 4

Disk 3 ends after you defeat Seifer in Lunatic Pandora (the obelisk floating above Tear's Point). To get there Fly the Ragnarok into it, if you have entered before you come out to where the Ragnarok created a hole in it, if not you you'll see it happen as a semi cinematic (one of those ones that look pre-rendered yet it's still using the in-game model for the characters rather than the better looking pre-renders).

Shortly after you come off the Ragnarok you'll fight a Boss Battle against Fujin and Raijin, after that you can explore. I don't know the route but you'll come across another boss the [Mobile Type 8](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Mobile_Type_8) which blocks your way to Seifer. After you beat Mobile Type 8 you processed forward to face Seifer.

After beating Seifer he'll kidnap Rinoa you'll enter Disk 4. Be warned that once you do you'll be unable to leave Lunatic Pandora and return to the "normal" world map as such beating Seifer in Disk 3 is your Point of No Return for the game.

Following Seifer you'll come across a bitch of a boss battle against [Sorceress Adel](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Adel_(boss)) who is Junctioning Rinoa. Both are on the enemy side and become targets if you use Enemy Targeting attacks (GFs, Magic like Meteor). the bitch part of this battle is that is Rinoa dies it's game over and Adel will cast Absorb on her to recover and damage her AND Rinoa has way less HP than Adel so spamming GFs like normal won’t work (and strangely enough when I had Phoenix Auto-summon after the party is defeated it always killed Rinoa)

After getting past Adel this will trigger the story event where Ellone will cause Time Compression so that you can face Ultimecia. Before this you'll fight a bunch of Sorceresses in a continuous battle before coming to an area where you can now access Ultimecia's Castle.

NOTE: the reason why beating Seifer in Disk 3 is your Point of No Return is because while you can enter the World Map though Gates that are just before Ultimecia's Castle, most locations have a barrier around them prevent you from entering (I believe Tears Point, Fire Cavern, the diamond structure where Odin was found and the Chocobo forests are the places you can still enter. Lunatic Pandora I also believe disappears).

You can find the Ragnarok somewhere on the World Map (I don't recall but it was a hike) and inside will be a Card Club Member who will operate as an Item and Weapons Shop (and you can play cards with him). Also while you are outside of Ultimecia's Castle your abilities won’t be sealed (they are unsealed when you exit the front door but become resealed when you re-enter it)

Comment: I fly the Ragnarock into the Lunatic Pandora and nothing happens.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn that doesn't seem right. have you tried flying into it at each of the 4 sides? maybe you have to fly into the side you made the hole in if it was done so already (i don't know which)